# Change image in Datagridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the image of a cell but I keep getting an error message stating that it could not convert boolean?

Below is my code not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. It says boolean so I thought it was a problem with the if statement, since that checks if its true or not.

But that is okay: I placed a debug message and it worked just fine. The problem is trying to set the value of the specific cell to an image.

```
Image heartbeat = Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\alive.ico");
DataGridViewImageColumn alive = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
DataTable stores = new DataTable();
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=db.sqlite;Version=3;");
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select NO, NO2, CODE, IP_ADDRESS from lite", m_dbConnection);
adapter.Fill(stores);
dataGridView1.DataSource = stores;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(alive);
alive.Image = image;
dataGridView1.Columns[alive.Name].DisplayIndex = 1;
foreach(DataGridViewRow rrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(rrow.Cells["IP_ADDRESS"].Value.ToString() == "")
    {
        rrow.Cells[alive.Name].Value = heartbeat;
    }
    else
    {
        //alive.Image = heartbeat;
    }

}
```

Error message:

```
System.FormatException:Value 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' cannot be converted to type Boolean'
```

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: Change type of `DataGridViewColumn` to `DataGridViewImageColumn`

Comment: @Fabio it is already set to DataGridViewImageColumn

Comment: Show how you got data to the `DataGridView`. It is possible that Column bounded to the `Boolean` type.

Comment: @Fabio here ya go thanks

Comment: Check your column `alive`

Comment: @Fabio check what about the column everything looks okay to me.

Comment: Show how it is created. Because it seems that `Cells[alive.Name].Value`expect a `Boolean` type.

Comment: @Fabio I have added the rest of the code there isn't anything else all of this is when the form loads.....and image is already set to it...but i do a for loop to change the image to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...I set alive.Image = null and then everything worked fine.

Thanks,